Model is jittery when weight paint rigging
I am trying to weight paint my model for my rig, but it seems that the weight painting isn't responding when I start painting. Other than that it seems the texture of the model is jittery (you can see in the picture how it has different shades of blue) when I switch to texture paint.
I am using Mac if it is relevant.
What should I do to fix that?



Hello could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Just edited the post and added a link to the file

Thanks for the update. The model looks normal in Blender 4.2.0. There are no shades of blue. Weight painting works also properly. You know you need to paint the vertices, not the faces, right?

To see the weight paint I have to switch to Solid shading (Z). In Material Preview, I only see the light blue smurf color but no weight paint color as in your screenshot... ?!

I agree with Blunder, it seems to work the way it should
